# Is hasattr() a method?

Tags: python, oop, semantics, hasattr

Is `hasattr()` a method? It does take an object instance as a parameter, but it is not used as `object.hasttr()`. I would say it is not a method then?

Comment: [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) is a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Everything in Python is an object*, even functions and methods. So the fact that `hasattr()` takes an object is nothing special, so do `str()` and `input()` and `sum()`.

A method is a function that has been *bound* to an object by accessing it as an attribute; so `"foo bar".split` gives you the bound `str.split` method:

```
>>> "foo bar".split
<built-in method split of str object at 0x7f84bef6a730>
```

This one happens to be “built-in” because it is implemented as part of the Python runtime, but it’s no different from a function on a class written in Python.

Calling it returns the result of the method *as applied to the string it is bound to*:

```
>>> method = "foo bar".split
>>> method()
['foo', 'bar']
```

I can also use it directly, *unbound*:

```
>>> str.split("spam ham")
['spam', 'ham']
```

`hasattr()` is not bound. It's a function. You can't bind it like you could with Python functions even if your tried<sup>*</sup>.

Python functions, added to a class, become methods automatically when you access them as an attribute on an instance of the class:

```
>>> class KnightsWhoSayNi:
...     pass
...
>>> def speak(self): return "Ni!"
...
>>> speak
<function speak at 0x10fe65f28>
>>> knight = KnightsWhoSayNi()
>>> hasattr(knight, "speak")  # using that function you mentioned!
False
>>> KnightsWhoSayNi.speak = speak  # adding the function to the class
>>> knight.speak   # now it exists! As a method...
<bound method speak of <__main__.KnightsWhoSayNi object at 0x10fe71080>>
>>> knight.speak()
'Ni!'
```

Note how `speak()` was given an argument named `self`, but I didn't have to pass it in. Because the method is *bound* to a specific instance of the class, that's taken care of automatically. The first argument passed in is the instance. The name doesn't even matter, but `self` is the convention, best stick to that.

As an exercise, you could try the above example yourself. Then try adding `hasattr` to the class. You'll find that you can`t use it like a method, it won't become bound via` knight.hasattr`, the instance won't be passed in as the first argument, you will still have to pass in two arguments for it to work at all.

If you wanted to go off the deep end, you could learn about how binding works in the [Python Descriptors HOW-TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Don’t worry if that feels too big of a step, that’s quite advanced.

---

<sup>*</sup> To pre-empt not-picking: You can *emulate* binding by using [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or [`functools.partialmethod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod), but that’s not quite the same thing.